# Pysnmp getCmd returning int 0 instead of Integer('noError',...)

Tags: pysnmp, pyasn1

I have installed the following pip packages on Oracle Linux 9:

```
pysnmp           4.4.12
pysnmp-mibs      0.1.6
```

On Centos 7 I have installed:

```
pysnmp-4.2.5-2.el7.noarch
```

Using pysnmp cmdgen `getCmd()`,

```
from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413.oneliner import cmdgen

cmdGen = cmdgen.CommandGenerator()
errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = cmdGen.getCmd(...)
```

I am getting errorStatus of Python int 0 on Oracle 9 while the CentOS 7 box gives an object:

```
 Integer('noError', NamedValues(('noError', 0), ('tooBig', 1), ('noSuchName', 2), ('badValue', 3), ('readOnly', 4), ('genErr', 5), ('noAccess', 6), ('wrongType', 7), ('wrongLength', 8), ('wrongEncoding', 9), ('wrongValue', 10), ('noCreation', 11), ('inconsistentValue', 12), ('resourceUnavailable', 13), ('commitFailed', 14), ('undoFailed', 15), ('authorizationError', 16), ('notWritable', 17), ('inconsistentName', 18)))
```

Why is the Oracle Linux 9 box returning only `int` 0, not the object like the CentOS 7 box?

Answer (score 0):

That's simply because this is a Python library.

The relevant source code should be [here](https://github.com/lextudio/pysnmp/blob/v6.0.5/pysnmp/entity/rfc3413/cmdgen.py#L326) that you either get a simple `int` of `0`, or an `Integer` object from the PDU.

But the meaning is the same, no error is returned.